# socket gaierror in Splunk and python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using splunk-SDK to collect the API to get the data.

```
import time
import splunklib.client as client
import splunklib.results as results

HOST = "iaasn00033501"
PORT = 8089
USERNAME = "XXXXXX"
PASSWORD = "XXXXXX"
# Create a Service instance and log in 
service = client.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD)
```

I got the error socket.gaierror: [Errno-2] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

Really appreciated your help.

Comment: I am running this on windowspowershell.

Comment: It looks like it simply cannot connect to that host. Have you confirmed that hostname is correct, and tried connecting to it via other means?

Comment: Hi Cody, you are right, basically, once I put full host address, the issue is fixed.